# Calling a static method inside a class in jar file

Tags: java

I want to execute specific method inside class in jar file which is don't have main method, with java command I tried `java -cp classes.jar com.example.test.Application` but I get this error `Error: Could not find or load main class` After decompile jar file I have found Application class inside it is there any way to call a static function inside Application class in a jar file?

Comment: you cannot do this. write a test case. thats what tests are for isn't it?

Comment: create another class with a main method that calls your static method.

Comment: @MauricePerry this is jar file how can i create another class with main method?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? You create a new Java class that calls the method in question.

Comment: @Daniel.V just because you can't create a main method in that jar, doesn't mean you can't create a main methodµ

Comment: As other comments have said, this is not something you should do or want to do. You could write a main class which calls the static function in question reflectivly. An alternative which is really hacky and will cause initialization problems is to call your static function from a  static initializer.

Comment: Are you using JavaFX by any chance?

Comment: @Daniel.V put your class in another jar file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use **Jshell**:

```
$ jshell --class-path  ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.4
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join("a", "b", "c")
$1 ==> "abc"
```

Or create a java class with main  compile it and run with java:

**Test.java:**

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join("a", "b", "c");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Compile and run**:

```
$ javac -cp /path/to/jar/commons-lang3-3.9.jar  Test.java
$ java -cp /path/to/jar/commons-lang3-3.9.jar:.  Test
abc
```